# Linux Mint takes 6+ hours to shut down

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown

I have recently installed Linux Mint MATE. The first two days it took a little longer to turn off (compared to when Windows 10 was installes) but I figured it was within normal range.

Yesterday after having it on the entire day, I powered it off. It logged out, the screen went black and then... stayed that way. I thought it would just take a little longer and went to sleep. 6+ hours later, it was still stuck there!

This is a fresh Mint 20.2 Uma installation and the only things I have installed are libsdl2-dev and vscode. I also transfered a 100+GB backup to the hard drive during the day.

How do I find out why this is happenning? How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome, *"transfered a 100+GB backup"*, can you check your disk isn't full?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thank you! Strangely, Disc manager says I have 737GB of space available even though my Hard Drive's capacity is 500GB.

Comment: It says I'm using 244GB of storage, so there's plenty of space left.